# /etc/hosts : Block the Entire Website but Enable One Folder

Tags: windows, website, blocking, hosts-file

The below entry in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file will block the site `www.rauf.com`.

```
127.0.0.1 www.rauf.com
```

That's fine.
Now I'm looking for more advanced control just with this file. I want to block all content of this site except one folder which is `www.rauf.com/business`. Is it possible ?

Comment: "Is it possible?" - no

Comment: The entire website will have the same indistinguishable IP. Even many firewalls cannot do this.

Comment: Also, be aware that Windows **bypasses the hosts lists** for specific sites. See https://www.csoonline.com/article/2641599/microsoft-hosts-file-bypass-issue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not possible - that's not how it works.

`hosts` file controls how domain names are resolved to IP addresses. Strictly speaking it can be used to override resolution of some domains. Domain names and IP addresses are universal for the internet (and networking in general): they're used on the web, but also by email, VPN, Minecraft multiplayer and so on.

The path - the thing that follows the domain name in HTTP links - is specific to HTTP - the protocol that the modern web was built on. It's not a universal thing that all protocols use. Some protocols don't need the ability to specify a resource or handle it differently than with paths.

The domain name resolution system thus doesn't know what a path is. Your browser resolves the domain to an IP address first, then connects to it and talks using HTTP. The path is only a thing on the latter stage. That means that the `hosts` file entry is interpreted before the path even starts to exist conceptually and at that stage the resolver has to decide which IP address to return: the real one or the "blocking" one. It can't take the path into account because it doesn't understand or have it.

Comment: Is there any alternative ways ?